# Couldnt find new button to create new field in standard object(Task)

Tags: administration, activities

Couldn't find new button to create new field in standard object(Task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks and Events are actually both the Activities object in the background, so you'll need to create them on that object. See this help article for the exact steps:

[Create Custom Fields for Tasks or Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387017&type=1)